# Google App Engine: Backends not responding today! Any issues?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, backend

Error: Server Error

The service you requested is not available yet.
Please try again in 30 seconds

This is the story from the morning today!  15 hours ago, it worked fine. All of a sudden the logs stopped responding. So, I thought I'd check later. Now, I see the same error again and again. I am working on resolving a Production issue and I need to get this fixed! Can someone help me pleasE?

Comment: StackOverflow is not an appropriate place for this question; the Google App Engine support website is.  (And if you look at http://code.google.com/status/appengine, you'll see that indeed there is some stuff possibly going wrong that's not your fault.)

Comment: Yeah! We did report issue on our premium support! but not sure when we would get response from them. Thats why I posted here! But actually, they got back to us and investigating the issue. Thanks Louis! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your paiments is active? If not - there is only 9h of free backend/per day. Maybe you use it all?

Check it with admin console in your applications.